# Difficulties with distribute -

Tags: python, distutils

am new to Python packaging and am trying to work out which flags I need to get something uploaded properly into PyPi. [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html) seems to building things them deleting them straight away. How do I stop that from happening?

Here is the traceback:

```
tim@falcon:~/Code/slate$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/slate.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/slate.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/slate.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/slate.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'src/slate.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
creating slate-0.2.3
creating slate-0.2.3/src
creating slate-0.2.3/src/slate
creating slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
making hard links in slate-0.2.3...
hard linking .gitignore -> slate-0.2.3
hard linking LICENSE -> slate-0.2.3
hard linking README -> slate-0.2.3
hard linking setup.py -> slate-0.2.3
hard linking src/slate/__init__.py -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate
hard linking src/slate/slate.py -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate
hard linking src/slate.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
hard linking src/slate.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
hard linking src/slate.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
hard linking src/slate.egg-info/requires.txt -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
hard linking src/slate.egg-info/top_level.txt -> slate-0.2.3/src/slate.egg-info
Writing slate-0.2.3/setup.cfg
tar -cf dist/slate-0.2.3.tar slate-0.2.3
gzip -f9 dist/slate-0.2.3.tar
removing 'slate-0.2.3' (and everything under it)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message seems to indicate that the script removed a temporary directory created to do your package... The `.tar.gz` file is not removed. Check your `dist` directory for it.

To upload you can probably use [`distutils`-documented](http://docs.python.org/distutils/uploading.html) way:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Some good reads:

- [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils) -- Official documentation on how to distribute python packages
- [The hitchhiker's guide to python packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/)

Comment: Oh stupid me! I'll accept the answer when the time limit allows, ~5 min.